# Shared database between Daedalus and Cardano-node

Tags: cardano-node, daedalus

I just started diving into the command line tools and as a first step I want to get a Cardano node running. My question is, whether it's a good idea to use the database from the Daedalus wallet (under *$HOME/Library/Application Support/Daedalus Mainnet/chain* on macOS) and point the cardano-node argument *database-path* there? Will there be any conflicts between the node instance and Daedalus, perhaps when running them at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something like this on Linux to conserve space. Only one node can share the chain state at the same time though. Further, if you switch back and forth between newer/older version of cardano-node, it will trigger ledger state rebuilds which take a while before the node is functioning. If your only goal is to be able to use the CLI, you can start Daedalus and set `CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH` to the path in Daedalus.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I noticed the rebuild after launching Daedalus again, which is actually a dealbreaker then for me for this setup. In any case, your suggestion is perhaps the best way for now, thanks for this hint. Just a quick follow-up question: I am not sure where the socket is actually located, I can't find it either in Application Support or within the App package...

Comment: Ah, just found a post that it's supposed to be at $HOME/Library/Application Support/Daedalus Mainnet/cardano-node.socket